# Function to see whether variable has values but it is zero

Tags: php

If we need to check whether the variable is set or not, we can easily check it by function isset()

But what about is_zero?

But

```
isset($myvar)
```

doesn't accomplish my task. If we use isset($myvar) then PHP would return false always and If I use

```
if(empty($myvar))
```

then I get Notice:

```
Notice: Undefined index: $myvar
```

I thought it must be there in PHP, because sometimes we need to store the zero value variables also.

I tried this:

```
if(is_zero($myvar))
    echo $myvar;
```

But got this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_zero()

Maybe a bug in PHP ?

Comment: What exactly is "zero"? Do you mean `null`?

Comment: `empty($myvar)` will never ever throw an *Undefined index* notice.

Comment: It is still extremely unclear what exactly you're asking, the best I can do is point you to this: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is_zero is not a PHP function, you can write your own:

```
function is_zero($input)
{
    if($input === 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

if there is a possibility that $input is not defined earlier, you can add & in front of $input or @ in front of is_zero to hide a possible notice error.

```
function is_zero(&$input)
{
    if($input === 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

or

```
if(@is_zero($variable))
```

Comment: Could simply just be `function is_zero($input) { return $input === 0; }`

Comment: Doesnt look simple at all. But there are more ways to do the trick ;)

Comment: Do you really need a function for `=== 0`?

Comment: **Note:** this will show error if the variable `$input` is not defined

Comment: `if(@$input === 0)` is completely pointless, because `$input` is guaranteed to exist inside the function, because it's in the function signature. If anything the notice will be thrown here: `is_zero($variable)`, not inside the function. And error suppression is extremely frowned upon.

Comment: You are right, I made a typo, replaced @ with & in my example code.

Answer (score 0):

Check [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/empty) function: It checks whether the value is 0 also.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check if a variable is zero by adding a exclamation mark in front of the variable like this:

```
if(!$myVar)
{

}
```

Comment: Note that this also matches `null`, `false`, `''`, `'0'` and `array()`, not only `0`.

Answer (score 0):

empty() will not show you `Notice: Undefined index: $myvar`.

If the variable is not set or if its value is zero , it returns 1

so you should have got error while printing it

`echo $myvar`

If the variable is not set you cannot print it

so for checking is set  and is zero use this

```
if(empty($myvar)){
    if(isset($myvar))
    echo $myvar;
     else
       echo "variable not set";  
}
```

Comment: For "is set but empty" I'd rather use `if (isset($var) && !$var)` than both `isset` and `empty` together. It does the same thing.

Comment: yes correct. But i just want him to understand the different scenarios .so only i used `if else`